# União de vetores em Python

Tags: python

> Olá, preciso fazer uma união entre dois vetores em python, mas sem usar as funções de list
> por algum motivo meu código está dando errado era para sair 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 9, mas está saindo como 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 4, 2, 9, 5

```
def union (x,y):
  aux1 = x+y
  aux2 = []
  aux3 = " "

  for i in aux1: 
    if i not in aux2:
      aux3 += str(i) + ' '
  return aux3

a = [7, 2, 5, 8, 4]
b = [4, 2, 9, 5]
print(union(a,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer a união, você pode modificar a função somando as listas `a` e `b` e as transformando em um `set` (que é responsável por remover os valores duplicados).

Ficaria assim:

```
def union(x, y):
  aux3 = ''
  s = set(x + y)
  for i in s:
    aux3 += str(i) + ' '
  return aux3

a = [7, 2, 5, 8, 4]
b = [4, 2, 9, 5]

print(union(a, b))
```

EDIT: Se não puder usar o `set`, talvez isto sirva para resolver o problema:

```
def union(x, y):
  aux3 = ''
  x.extend(i for i in y if i not in x)
  for i in x:
     aux3 += str(i) + ' '
  return aux3

a = [7, 2, 5, 8, 4]
b = [4, 2, 9, 5]

print(union(a, b))
```

Ou ainda se você preferir usar seu código original, só ficou faltando adicionar os números na lista `aux2`:

```
def union (x,y):
  aux1 = x+y
  aux2 = []
  aux3 = ""

  for i in aux1: 
    if i not in aux2:
      aux3 += str(i) + ' '
      aux2.append(i) # ou aux2 += [i]
  return aux3

a = [7, 2, 5, 8, 4]
b = [4, 2, 9, 5]
print(union(a,b))
```

Comment: Então é que meu professor, está obrigando o pessoal a n usar nenhuma função de lista além do len, só as funções dos vetores a gente pode usar

Answer (score 2):

Você criou uma lista (ou vetor) vazio, o aux2. E você está fazendo checagem (if not in) nessa lista vazia (e você não adiciona nada durante a função). Como não se pode utilizar as funções da lista, e portanto você precisa utilizar uma string ao invés de uma lista para armazenar o resultado, você deve então checar se o número a ser adicionado ao aux3, está na string aux3.

```
aux1 = x+y
# Pode se descartar aux2, deixarei o nome como aux3 para facilitar a visualização
aux3 = ''

for i in aux1:
     # Nesse 'if' é necessário que você faça a checagem, criando uma função
     # No caso eu dei exemplo a função checar
     if i not in aux3:
          aux3 += str(i) + ' '
return aux3
```

Comment: eu devo ter a mentalidade de um primata, pq eu realmente n entendi o que vc quis dizer sério

Comment: Basicamente, você está checando se o número está num vetor vazio, por conta disso você está adicionando números repetidos. O que você deve fazer portanto é, checar se o número está na string aux3. Vou dar um exemplo de código no comentário acima